# on long click listener delete item in list dialog

Tags: android

**I am using a dialog** which is show the item of list of string my code is

```
 final CharSequence[] items = {"1", "2", "3"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }).show();
```

now my question is how to implement **onLongClicklistener** method **to delete a selected item** my dialog is looking like shown in image
[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: Create Custom dialogClass and you can do this easily

Comment: finally i found the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145628/add-onlongclick-listener-to-an-alertdialog

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `onItemLongClick` method as follows:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
        // TODO: Get the position of the item clicked. 
        //       Delete it from your collection eg.ArrayList.
        //       Call notifydatasetChanged so that it will refresh 
        //       the views displaying updated list.
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: sdevani92 did not mention about any listView

Comment: He did not mention categorically that he is not using listview too.

Comment: so please explain that how he can show listview in alertDialog

Comment: @RohanPawar i am using a AlertDialog not a ListView and pass the array of string.

Comment: you can also create an costum dialog which contains a listview and use the onItemLongClick method to remove the pressed item

Comment: @sdevani92 already i mentioned that you have to create custom dialog see comment below your question

Answer (score 0):

1) Set an ItemLongClickListener on your listview
2) remove the long pressed item from your array, which populates your list adapter
3) Refresh your adapter

```
public ListView listView;
public ArrayList<String> items;
public ArrayAdapter adapter;

listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){ 
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
    String selectedItem = items.get(pos);
    items.remove(selectedItem);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: @TheOnlyJackob sdevani92 did not mention about any listView

Comment: yes i am using a AlertDialog @TheOnlyJakobob not listView

Comment: then just remove the view on the clicked item: view.setVisability(GONE);

Comment: but hear my requirement is remove the item on long press of item only.

Comment: and what is an item? item is a part of a listview and your sketch looks like a listview. if you dont have it with the alert dialog, creat a costum dialog and populate it with your items